# Using List in DynamoDB from AWS with different type of objects

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

In aws when you build the code in MobileHub it builds some DO classes in one of my classes I am using a List of dynamodb, this List contains another List that ressembles an object something like

```
{L:
  [{L:
    [{S:"Something", 
      BOOL: true
    }]
  }]
}
```

How am I supposed to un/marshall this in Android(Java)?

I'm having trouble because the list is not made up only by Strings, there is a BOOL in there.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mobile Hub generates DO classes that use the DynamoDB object mapper library.  The DynamoDB object mapper does not currently support lists containing mixed types. If possible it would be less work for you to use a different schema; however, if you must do this you would need to use the DynamoDB client directly and use a json library that properly handles lists of mixed types.